# Handling command line options with multiple arguments for some flags

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a program where the command line usage should be something like:

`mkblueprint FILE FILE FILE -o <output name> -s <string> -r <number> -p pOPT1 pOPT2 pOPT3`

I'm currently using [CmdLib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdlib) and I can't figure out a way to handle this; a flag is required for each input(so I can't just have FILEs sitting alone) and there doesn't appear to be a way to pass multiple arguments to a flag, as with `-p`. These are extremely common in command line programs so I figure I'm just misunderstanding the documentation, but it's not mentioned in any command line library I look at for Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more work with CmdLib I was able to handle the bare FILE input via the `Extra` tag and then checking that each string is a valid file, which seems to be the standard way to handle it despite the name. `-p pOPT1 pOPT2 pOPT3` is apparently not allowed under the POSIX standard, which is why I'm not finding libraries that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the [`GetOpt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/System-Console-GetOpt.html) bindings that come with `base`. They're not as sexy as some of the more modern alternatives, but they support bare arguments and final options well.

Comment: Apparently my actual problem was wanting to parse the options in a non-posix compliant manner.